# How do I implement a VIDEO gallery like gallery formatter but with videos?

Tags: 7, files, media

I need to implement a gallery of videos in DRUPAL 7 like gallery formatter in Drupal 7 but with videos.

The videos are from YOUTUBE.  I created a content type named "video" and I have used the module:  http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field for upload the code of video.  Have you any idea for create the video galleries?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If you're able to switch to a module other than video_embed_field I'd highly recommend the [Media module](http://drupal.org/project/media) along with the [Media Gallery module](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery).

You'll also want [Media Youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube), I've used those three together quite a bit and they're very good.

I'd also recommend installing [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) to take advantage of the built-in lightbox features.

Comment: The Media Gallery module is in beta... Have you experienced it's trustable for your production site?

Answer (score 4):

Also, check out the [MediaFront](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront) module. It is a front end media solution for Drupal. It employs an innovative and intuitive administration interface that allows the website administrator to completely customize the front end media experience for their users without writing any code. In addition to this amazing module is the built-in Open Standard Media (OSM) Player.

You can embed your youtube videos, customize the look of the player, create playlist or galleries using views and much more.

Answer (score 4):

The video_embed_field module is great. Now you just need to create a view to display a table or grid of thumbnail images and then link them to the node display page to display the embedded youtube video.

Checkout the [video page](http://goldwing.mototribe.com/g-videos) on my site. It combines youtube videos with uploaded videos from the video module. When I did it a few months ago you couldn't link the thumbnail to the node display. If that's still not fixed just use a simple rewrite to "node/[nid]".

Comment: Yes, and how can I do for the view be similar to display of gallery formatter?

Comment: not sure what the "gallery formatter" looks like but you can modify and theme your views output in many ways.

Comment: hi MotoTribe. how work related videos in your video page?

Comment: it's just a view with a "taxonomy term" contextual filter, similar to: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17920/related-content-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 3):

Personally I wasnt finding the media module pleasant to work with so based on several other modules I created a feature called [youtube_importer_feature](http://drupal.org/project/youtube_importer_feature). Together with [video_filter](http://drupal.org/project/video_filter) and [video_filter_field](http://drupal.org/project/video_filter_field) (plus the patches I added [here](http://drupal.org/node/1417106) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/1372502) that they havent committed yet) you can import directly from youtube json api and then display those videos in any way you like but most importantly using views.