# Get a node using the same category (taxonomy term) the current node is using

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have two types of nodes: *News* and *Page*. 
Every *News* node can be assigned to a category (taxonomy term), which is used also from the *Page* nodes.

I would like to get in a view all the *News* nodes that have the same category the current node has.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can't do it for you, so no answer, just a hint: experiment with relationships.

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but there is no expected results.

Comment: I don't have time to try from scratch, but if you'll add what you tried to your question, I might be able to spot mistakes. And if not me, then someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add CONTEXTUAL FILTER (Earlier arguments) on CONTEXTUAL FILTERS section on views click add, select "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" and in "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL" choose Provide default value. Choose "Taxonomy ID from URL" check "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks". It will create a related taxonomy.

Comment: I did it and no results. My node link is "localhost/page-slug".

Comment: Make sure you have shared taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to show a list of **News** nodes on a **Page** node that share a given taxonomy term, then you can do this:

- Create a **Taxonomy Reference** field on the **Page** content type. If you prefer, you could create an **Entity Reference** field instead.
- Assign the same taxonomy reference field to the **News** content type.
- Create your view. Add fields and filters to your view from the **News** Content type.
- Add **Has Taxonomy Term** ID as a contextual filter.
- Under **When the filter value is not available**, choose **Taxonomy term ID from URL**. Enable **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**, and **Limit terms by vocabulary**, then choose the shared vocabulary.
- Under **When the filter value *is* available or a default is provided** choose **Specify validation criteria**. Set the **Validator Term** to Taxonomy Term and choose the shared vocabulary.
- Under **Filter value type** choose **Term name converted to term ID**.
- Under **Action to take if filter value does not validate** choose **Display all results for specified field**.
- Test by previewing with the NID from a Page node that shares a vocabulary term with at least 1 News node.

Note that this approach does not require any Relationships in the view. There are a lot of posts that deal with similar problems that add one or two relationships to the view, but they aren't needed here and, even if they work, are a lot more complicated and slower for Views to execute.

Comment: This was really helpful, I'll add that I couldn't test the preview with the page node ID but it worked with the ID of the taxonomy term instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link:
[Related content in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17920/related-content-in-drupal-7)

You need to create a view and add a contextual filter to display the nodes based on the particular taxonomy term from the currently active node.

Make sure you are not having the views filter for one particular node type.